# Error occured 'int' object is not callable while apply sum() method with lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I am trying simple program to get sum of elements in a list but this gives me error  '**int' object is not callable**  i am using python 3.7

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,1,4,5] 
Sum = sum(numbers) 
print(Sum)
```

Comment: It works well. What is wrong?

Comment: It's not advised to use keywords as variables names. Use `total_sum` or something like this instead of keyword `Sum`. And, yes even as it is it works fine.

Comment: Most likely you assigned something to `sum` or `print` somewhere in your program/notebook. Please clarify whether or not this is the case. If necessary restart the program/notebook and execute only the code shown. Provide the full [repro] if the error persists and this isn't the full code.

Comment: @DenisRasulev `Sum` is not a keyword. `sum` is not even a keyword. While shadowing a builtin is typically a bad idea, the biggest problem with `Sum` is that it violates PEP-8 capitalization sessions (though others might argue that two identifiers that differ only by case is just as bad, if not worse).

Comment: @chepner What does "capitalization sessions" mean? I've never heard "sessions" in that usage before.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with the given code. You need to make a [mre].

Comment: @wjandrea It means "I hate autocorrect". That should be "capitalization suggestions".

Answer (score 0):

create a new file and copy all commands to new file

[My problem was solved after creating a new file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGEIr.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).